# How to insert a Gap in y axis with coord_flip

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to insert a gap in the y axis from 0.5 - 0.8 to make the graph nicer because there is too much space until 1 ( I'm showing odds ratio).

I have already tried with https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html package but it doesn't work. Also I have seen previous answer about the topic but they seems not to fit with `coord_flip` and the vertical line.

Here is the example data set:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggplot2)

labels2 <- c("Overall", "Catsfood", "dogsfood")
oddsratio2 <- c(0.05, 0.07, 0.03)
lower2 <- c(0.03, 0.04, 0.02)
upper2 <- c(0.15, 0.3, 0.1)

dfhelp <- data.frame(labels2, oddsratio2, lower2, upper2)


dfhelp |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = labels2, y = oddsratio2, ymin = lower2,
             ymax = upper2))+
  geom_pointrange()+
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.08)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0)),
                     breaks = seq(0,1.5,0.25))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1/1.5)+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12))+
  coord_flip(ylim = c(0,1.1))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use a scale transformation to avoid the need for a break in the scale. It's also possible to skip `coord_flip` in most cases since 2020's ggplot2 3.3.0.

```
dfhelp |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = oddsratio2, y = labels2, xmin = lower2, xmax = upper2))+
  geom_pointrange() +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.08) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, lty = 2)+
  # scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 0.05),
  #                    breaks = c(0.1, seq(0,1.1,0.2))) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::log10_trans(),
                     breaks = 1 / c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100)) +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1/1.5)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12))
```

[image]

... much less blank space than an unadjusted view:

[image]

Comment: Good point, updated with pure log scale.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Spring that look much better.

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron for the clarification!